# How to pull a sorted list from Core Data when the entity has a relation to another entity

Tags: ios, core-data, nssortdescriptor

I have two entities: `Product` and `Category`. They are defined like this:

**PRODUCT**

name = string

code = string

fromCategory = relation to category, `toOne`

**CATEGORY**

category = string

toProduct = relation to product, `toMany`

So one product can only belong to one category and a category can be assigned to many products.

This is the problem. I have products like this:

- laser ship (toy)
- doll (toy)
- red mercedes (car)
- robot (sci-fi)
- peach (fruit)
- apple (fruit)
- aston martin (toy)
- mouse (computer)

If I pull a list from core data sorted by the name I get this

- apple (fruit)
- aston martin (toy)
- doll (toy)
- laser ship (toy)
- mouse (computer)
- peach (fruit)
- red mercedes (car)
- robot (sci-fi)

but what I want is this:

- mouse (computer)
- red mercedes (computer)
- apple (fruit)
- peach (fruit)
- robot (sci-fi)
- aston martin (toy)
- doll (toy)
- laser ship (toy)

In other words, I want it primarily sorted by the category and then by the name, cause I want related items to be together on the table view.

This is the code I have to pull it sorted by the product's name:

```
@interface NSObject (ProductsBundlesExtensions)

+(NSArray *)sortDescriptorArrayByKey:(NSString *)key;

@end


@implementation NSObject (ProductsBundlesExtensions)



+(NSArray *)sortDescriptorArrayByKey:(NSString *)key {
  return @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:key
                                       ascending:YES
                                        selector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)]];
}

@end


+ (NSArray*)allSortedItemsInContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
{
  NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

  request.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:NSStringFromClass([self class])
                               inManagedObjectContext:context];

  // sorting by product's name
  [request setSortDescriptors:[NSObject sortDescriptorArrayByKey:@"name"]];

  NSError *error;
  NSArray *all = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

  return all;
}
```

This is my problem: how do I do a sort by the category if that is an entity relation? What `NSSortDescriptor` will do that? Sort by the relation and then by the name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vanadian solution did not work for me because the category relation is a one to many type. I read on the web that you cannot sort by a relation that has one-to-many and that was why the app was crashing.

The correct answer for my case is that it is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Just use two sort descriptors (the NSObject category is too restricted to be used)

```
[request setSortDescriptors:@[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"fromCategory.category"] 
                                                           ascending:YES 
                                                            selector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:),
                             [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name"] 
                                                           ascending:YES 
                                                            selector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)]];
```

You could extend the category to consider multiple keys

```
+ (NSArray *)sortDescriptorArrayByKeys:(NSArray<NSString *> *)keys {
  NSMutableArray *descriptors = [NSMutableArray array];
  for (NSString *key in keys) {
    [descriptors addObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:key
                                                         ascending:YES
                                                          selector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)]];
  }
  return [descriptors copy];
}
```

Then you can write

```
[request setSortDescriptors:[NSObject sortDescriptorArrayByKeys:@[@"fromCategory.category", @"name"]]];
```

Comment: one thing is strange on your answer, that is `@"category.name"`. `Product` entity has the project called `fromCategory` but this is a relation. I suppose by `@"category.name"` you mean `@"fromCategory.name"` but can you do that? `fromCategory` has no property called `name`. I am sure this will crash (I am not on a phase I can test it right now)

Comment: I have tested it now and it is crashing the application :(

Comment: What's the reason of the crash?

Comment: xcode is not helping, as usual, the crash message is `libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException`.

Comment: I did, it does nothing. This is Xcode 8, iOS 10. Cannot run with Xcode 7 because this is a messages app. Don't tell me I am screwed... 

Comment: I don't use Xcode 8 yet, but you should be able to get the reason of the crash from the stack trace.

Comment: The problem is with the first sort descriptor. I remove that and it works.

Comment: It should work. Please check again the relationships and the spelling.

Comment: Definitively not working. I have triple checked everything. Not working.